# Shipping Method option not showing

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

I've set up a shipping method/zone purely for testing but it doesn't show up during checkout. :/

I created a shipping zone only for the state of Oregon:

[image]

And for the shipping method there's just ONE rule with the ONLY condition being that the shipping zone is Oregon:

[image]

Here's the code I have for the shipping page of the checkout process:
http://d.pr/n/fizP

Finally, when I go through the checkout process, I make sure that my shipping address uses Oregon as the state. I've confirmed this by using this on the shipping page (not seen in the code above): `{{ cart.shippingAddress.state }}`

What am I missing??

Comment: I'd first check if the shipping method works with the test templates included with Commerce...if it comes up there, but not your own, it's a template issue.  If it doesn't come up there, it points to a set up issue (perhaps something about the products in your cart that stops it being an available method?)

Comment: Hi Angie, I just tried to reproduce the same shipping method, zone and rule, and was able to have the shipping method show up on the front end. Silly question, but can you confirm the rule and method are 'enabled'?

Comment: Figured it out - the country wasn't being set. :/

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that the country wasn't being set properly. Since we're only shipping to the US, I had mistakenly commented out my hidden input for the country field.